# DHTML popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, dhtml

I am trying to make a DHTML window on my website and I can actually get it to popup for me.  The problem I am having with it is when it pops up it moves the text around on the page.  I have seen examples of DHTML popups where this doesn't occur for instance here: http://dhtmlpopups.webarticles.org/basics.php or here: http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/popup-window.php

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong the div tag for my popup looks like this

```
<div id="loginPopup" style="position: relative; display:none; z-index: 500;"><div class="closeButton" onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('loginPopup').style.display = 'none';"></div></div>
```

My site also use a template and css that I got off the net, could that be the problem?  I am at a loss for what to do to correct this, any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend that you put all your popup windows in a with width of 1px and a height of 1px position absolutely in the top corner of your page.  For two reasons...

1. You don't want pop up window markup mixed with everything else, as you may accidently one day put position:relative on the main div and this will throw your window co-ordinates out of wack
2. If you want to remove the pop up div using javascript, its easier to find its parent in the Dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to position the div as 'absolute' not 'relative.'  I would then use the 'top' and 'left' attributes to position the window.

```
div.loginPopup {
   position:aboslute;
   top:50px;
   left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Both get a vote from me because I don't know who posted first!

Answer (score 1):

use absolute positioning if you don't want it to move your other elements.